# Qual a Diferença entre Rebin e Databind?

Tags: c#

Minha pergunta e sobre c#.

Gostaria de saber a diferença entre Rebind e Databind? que seja bem especifica!

Pois pesquiso nos sites e nunca vejo uma resposta que vai direto ao ponto.

Comment: não encontra pq "Rebind" não é um método dos objetos do framework .net. `DataBind` vincula uma fonte de dados a um objeto, um GridView por exemplo. "Rebind" seria teoricamente para atualizar ou re-vincular a fonte de dados, o que pode ser feito usando novamente o `DataBind`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Databind` é uma forma de "amarrar" o objeto (Ex: DataGrid) com uma fonte de dados(Ex: uma lista de determinado objeto).

`Rebind` na verdade não é um método ou algo semelhante, é apenas uma nomenclatura, um "apelido" para o efeito de re-executar o `Databind`.